# How to use ES6 in a custom Jest Node Environment?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

So far I can use perfectly ES6 syntax in my tests files, but when I try to set up a custom `jest-enviroment` I'm unable to use that syntax there. And then unable to test anything.

My custom jest-node-enviroment looks like:

```js
const Crawler = require('../../src/parser/crawler/Crawler.js');


const NodeEnvironment = require("jest-environment-node")
module.exports = class Environment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {

    await super.setup()

    if (!this.global.crawler) {
      this.global.crawler = Crawler;
      await super.setup()
    }
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown()
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script)
  }
}
```

And then when I run the test:

```sh
pkg ▶ yarn test
yarn run v1.22.10
$ jest
Determining test suites to run...Setting Up Test ENV
 FAIL  test/crawler/crawler.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /the/path/to/the/pkg/src/parser/crawler/Crawler.js:1
    import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | 
    > 2 | const Crawler = require('../../src/parser/crawler/Crawler.js');
        |                 ^
      3 | 
      4 | 
      5 | const NodeEnvironment = require("jest-environment-node")

      at Object.<anonymous> (test/config/environment.js:2:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.039 s
Ran all test suites.
Teardown Crawler
```

I'm using ES6 in all my code since I have set up a `@babel-register` at booting time.
And I would like to keep it that way.

The `jest.config.js` looks like:

```js
{
...
globalSetup: "./test/config/setup.js",
globalTeardown: "./test/config/teardown.js",
testEnvironment: "./test/config/environment",
transform: {
   "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

I have dug in the docs from Babel, Jest , and a lot of "solutions to this" here and on the internet but everyone talks the same, nobody talks about how to use it in a custom environment.

Comment: Not supported in current Jest version. Try `jest@next`. Is there a reason why you didn't do this in setupFiles?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jonsharpe . I new to this off unit testing and jest, i haven’t  idea that i could setup the globals on ‘setup’ file. Will try that 

Comment: Thanks Estus Flask , the edit comments feature is a mess down here .

Answer (score 0):

Well partially solved by not using a custom environment.

It's a little less ergonomic because now there is no global refernce to put things into. But it works.